# Error Failed to open properties file : AppManage.tra from Ant script

Tags: java, ant, tibco, tibco-business-works, tibco-designer

After building EAR file when i'm trying to extract XML file form the EAR i'm getting error  **[exec] Failed to open properties file : AppManage.tra**

```
 <property name="Appmanage" value="C:\tibco\etascbw513\tra\5.10\bin\AppManage.exe" />

<target name="extract">
<exec executable="${Appmanage}">
  <arg value="-export"/>
  <arg value="-ear"/>
  <arg value="${workdir}\Deploy\EARs\${project}.ear"/>
  <arg value="-out"/>
 <arg value="${workdir}\Deploy\EARs\${project}.xml"/>
  <arg value="-max"/>
</exec>
```

---

old Q :  can someone share simple build.xml to create ear file from ant script
details : i'm able to pull repositories with the help ant script now i want to create EAR file from ant script for Tibco BW. can any one share simple demo .

Comment: which version of BW are you using? 5.x or 6.x?

Comment: I'm using Tibco BW 5.x

Comment: Do you know how to do it from command line?

Comment: i've created EAR build from Tibco designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to solve this error using below steps.

1. try to check your environment variable path.
2. check TRA_HOME/bin/ using App manage utility.

Comment: Could you add more detail, please? Check for what? What are both of those supposed to look like?

Comment: this both steps are for above mentioned error solution. This type of error  "[exec] Failed to open properties file : AppManage.tra" is prevent sometimes because of the environment variable or app manage utility path change in Tibco. 

c:\tibco\Etascbw513\tra\5.10\bin - check this environment path and its for tibco version 8.4.

Answer (score 0):

This error "Failed to open properties file : AppManage.tra" occurs because the AppManage executable tries to look for AppManage.tra in the current execution directory and does not find it. In this particular case, the current execution directory would depend on where you are executing Ant from.

The correct way to avoid this error is to provide full path to the AppManage.tra file as an argument to the AppManage executable in the ant exec statement, as shown below, in the highlighted section (two new arguments are added "--propFile" and "full path to AppManage.tra"). Hope this helps.

```
 <property name="Appmanage" value="C:\tibco\etascbw513\tra\5.10\bin\AppManage.exe" />

<target name="extract">
<exec executable="${Appmanage}">
```

> ```
>   <arg value="--propFile"/>
>   <arg value="C:\tibco\etascbw513\tra\5.10\bin\AppManage.tra"/>
> ```

```
  <arg value="-export"/>
  <arg value="-ear"/>
  <arg value="${workdir}\Deploy\EARs\${project}.ear"/>
  <arg value="-out"/>
  <arg value="${workdir}\Deploy\EARs\${project}.xml"/>
  <arg value="-max"/>
</exec>
```